# Calling a class method upon creation of Python classes

Tags: python, class-method, initializer

I'd like to automatically run some code upon class creation that can call other class methods. I have not found a way of doing so from within the class declaration itself and end up creating a `@classmethod` called `__clsinit__` and call it from the defining scope immediately after the class declaration. Is there a method I can define such that it will get automatically called after the class object is created?

Comment: Class creation or instance creation?  Because both can be done, but the answer is different depending.

Comment: You can use metaclasses for this.  See for instance [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).

Comment: Aside: Please don't make up `__special_methods__`. That's reserved for the Python language. Use a `_single_underscore_prefix` if you want it to be private.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with a [**metaclass**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) or a [**class decorator**](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3129-class-decorators).

A class decorator (since 2.6) is probably easier to understand:

```
def call_clsinit(cls):
    cls._clsinit()
    return cls

@call_clsinit
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def _clsinit(cls):
        print "MyClass._clsinit()"
```

Metaclasses are more powerful; they can call code and modify the ingredients of the class before it is created as well as afterwards (also, they can be inherited):

```
def call_clsinit(*args, **kwargs):
    cls = type(*args, **kwargs)
    cls._clsinit()
    return cls;

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = call_clsinit

    @classmethod
    def _clsinit(cls):
        print "MyClass._clsinit()"
```

Comment: I'd add that at least from the text of the question, it's hard to tell why `__new__` or `__init__` don't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.6 there is `__init_subclass__` as defined in [PEP 487](https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/).